# How to use in-line CSS to align a button centre on mobile?

Tags: html, css, html-email

I've got a button in an email that I'm trying to align centre on mobile.

I planned on using media queries to do this e.g.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 390px) {
.button-center {}
```

But I'm unsure whether I can even target the 'align' part of the code in this way.

```
<tr>
  <td><table class="button-center" align="left" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
      <th bgcolor="#000000" style="border-radius: 30px; line-height: 100%; mso-padding-alt: 5px 30px 10px;"> <a href="https://" target="_blank" style="font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color: #FFFFFF; display: block; font-size: 16px; line-height: 26px; padding: 14px 36px; text-decoration: none;">Read now</a></th>
    </tr>
  </table></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 2):

The equivalent of the HTML `align` attribute in CSS can be one of two things:

- `margin:0 auto` if you use `align="center"`
- `float:left` or `float:right` if you use `align="left"` or `align="right"`

In your case, on mobile, you will need to both cancel the float effect created by the `align="left"` in your HTML with a `float:none;` *and* set the table to `margin:0 auto` to center it. In the end, your style would look something like this:

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 390px) {
.button-center { float:none; margin:0 auto; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for such a clear explanation - learning something new every day. I've got this working in my code now! Thanks again.